# Dafny: Generic method on a base type and a subset type?

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

Can I define a generic method on a base type and subset type?

For example, we might later use the generic function by having

- `T0` be the sets of integers, and
- `T1` be the non-empty sets of integers

I image something like:

```
method MergeAndTouch<T0, T1>(Touch: (T1,T1)->bool, Plus: (T0,T0)->T0, unit: T0, xs: seq<T1>, a: T1)
  requires T0 >= T1 // NOT ALLOWED
  requires Reflexive(Touch)
  requires Symmetric(Touch)
  requires IsAssociative(Plus)
  requires IsUnital(Plus, unit)
  requires forall i:T1, j:T1 :: Touch(Plus(i, j), i) && Touch(Plus(i, j), j)
  requires forall i:nat, j:nat :: i < j < |xs| ==> !Touch(xs[i], xs[j])
{
// code goes here
}
```

*I need this to exclude things like the empty set from the generic `Touch` while still having things like the empty set as the unit for operations such as `FoldLeft`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case [subset](https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-subset-types) language feature can be used. This is how it will look like

```
ghost function NonEmptySetExample<T(00)>() : (r: set<T>)
{
    var t : T :| true ; {t}
}

type NonEmptySet<T(00)> = s : set<T> |  s != {} 
     ghost witness NonEmptySetExample<T>()
```

You can use set methods (`in` here) on `NonEmptySet`.

```
ghost function Test<T(00)>(t: NonEmptySet<T>) : T 
{
    var x : T :| x in t; x
}
```

Additionally you can define method taking `set` as argument and call with `NonEmptySet`

```
method TypeMethod<T>(s: set<T>) 
{
}

method CallTypeMethodOnSubSet<T(00)>(t: NonEmptySet<T>)
{
   TypeMethod(t);
}
```

Note: [T(00)](https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-nonempty-types) means type parameter itself is non empty.

Comment: I got this working and with Divyanshu Ranjan got everything verifying. We wrote up our experience (with code examples) in https://towardsdatascience.com/nine-rules-to-formally-validate-rust-algorithms-with-dafny-part-1-5cb8c8a0bb92.